# Elasticsearch Script File in Local Mode

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

Using ElasticSearch, one can place scripts of various languages in ElasticSearch's `/config/scripts` directory, and they will be automatically loaded for use in Update requests and other types of operations. In my production environment, I was able to accomplish this and run a successful Update using the script.

So far, however, I've been unsuccessful in getting this feature to work when running a node in local mode for integration tests. I assumed that, since one can configure the ElasticSearch node, with an `elasticsearch.yml` on the classpath, one should also be able to add a `scripts` directory and place her desired script there, causing it to be loaded into the local node. That doesn't seem to be the case since when I try to execute an Update utilizing that script it cannot be found.

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: Unable to find on disk script scripts.my_script 
    at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.compile(ScriptService.java:269)
    at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.executable(ScriptService.java:417)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:194)
    ... 6 more
```

Does anyone know the proper way to do automatic script loading into a local ElasticSearch node for testing?

I am using the basic ElasticSearch client included in "org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:1.5.2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After perusing the source code, I discovered that the reason my script was not being picked up by Elasticsearch's directory watcher was because it was watching `user.dir`, the default configuration directory. The `scripts/` subdirectory would have had to have been under there for the node to pick up my script and load it into the `ScriptService` for it to be used during updates.

The configuration directory can be overridden in your `elasticsearch.yml` with the key `path.conf`. Setting that to somewhere in your project would allow you to load scripts during testing and add those scripts to version control as well. Make sure that under that directory is a `scripts/` directory; that is where your scripts will be loaded from.